# What tool can I use for a step through bar in a step through registration?

Tags: django, web-applications, jquery-plugins, registration

I would like to make a step through registration page such as in the following pic taken from [here](https://fundersclub.com/accounts/signup/):

[image: Step through registration]

I have found [Gaya's presentation cycle](http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/presentation-cycle-cycle-with-a-progressbar/) for a step through but it seems suited rather for presentations. If it matters, I am using Django for the back end.

Comment: There are several different front-end solutions (example: http://exacttarget.github.io/fuelux/#wizard) so you'll have to Google around and find one you like. You'll then want to use the Django Form Wizard (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) so you can validate the data submitted at each step.

Comment: This looks nice, thanks for your tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good deal of jquery tools you can piece together. Or you can download templates from git or wherever that do most of this for you. I've used the Smart Wizard from Tech Laboratory. Its free. And I didn't run into a lot of bugs with it...

http://techlaboratory.net/smartwizard/demo/basic

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I'll accept this answer until someone provides a more elaborate one.